# Bootstrap carousel causing white space in column under image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a simple 3 slide carousel to fit into a 6 space column. Every time I add the carousel, though, it comes back with a large white space at the bottom of the div. Can anyone tell me why this may be happening?

I've looked at setting a strict height on the div but then the site loses it's ability to be fully responsive when it is on mobile devices.

The site is here: http://mylomatt.mylio.com/stackoverflow.html

The blank space is directly below the image/carousel of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.carousel-inner` class has bottom padding of 120px. See line 1653 of custom.css. Remove that (or make it smaller) and you should be all set.

Comment: Wow. I looked at this for hours. I'm new to all of this so thank you very, very much. I really appreciate it.